# Finding out how many German words I do know

Tags: learning, resource, vocabulary, proficiency-test

I know a website offering a test for knowing how many words you know in English.

http://testyourvocab.com/

I would like to find something similar for the German language.

I've made some searches but I couldn't find anything. For finding the English one, it was enough to search for "test English words".

Do you know any?

**EDIT**

I've found [this site](http://www.siteslike.com/similar/testyourvocab.com) by making [this Google search](https://www.google.at/search?q=testyourvocab.com%20alternative&oq=testyourvocab.com%20alternative&aqs=chrome..69i57.3431j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). But I would like to find one for German..

Comment: Does it really help you to know a definite number? Test yourself by reading original texts in various levels from fairy tales to novels and newspapers, then you will know whether
your vocabulary is sufficient or not.

Comment: Thanks, I'm studying german with an apps which is focused on vocabulary. I should know between 700 and 1500 words. But my grammar is really bad.. and also the real application of these words.. I cannot read a comic of Mikey Mouse yes.. I read one word and I "decode it" and continue..

Comment: A method I would consider laborious, uninteresting and not very efficient. I never learnt a language this way.

Comment: Which way do you use? (I use space repeated http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition)

Comment: Never heard of such theories, and there are hundreds. For beginning I choose a simple one-volume course book with a beginner's dictionary and and beginner's grammar. Then I begin reading simple texts such as children's stories I find in public libraries. Those stories are simple, easy to understand as they are illustrated, and the stories are good.

Comment: Well, google does have some results for "test german words" as well ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: then could you please link one which is similar to the one I linked? Since I googled but I couldn't find nothing similar :-)

Comment: @Phira: I don't understand.. -1 to me? how can I edit my question?

Comment: @Revious My comment has been a comment to an answer that has since been converted to a comment (together with my comment) and subsequently the comment has been deleted. Therefore, you have never received -1 from me and I will delete my now incomprehensible comment.

Comment: Please note, that the website solution you are looking for is only as good as their integrated/established database. Therefore it is only part of a solution at all. I suggest you to use many different dictionaries, that are managed though one application and list their individual definitions on each query.

Comment: Well, a vocabulary test that ask for your month you were born is something fraudulent. I dislike those sites.

Comment: @c.p.: do you mean for privacy? then what about facebook... every ipermarkek, data mining and so on.. privacy had died.

Comment: Since you linked to testyourvocab.com, you might find this discussion interesting: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/6014/16419

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a German vocab test site very similar to the one in the question: https://wortschatz.tk/
Sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 18):

I'll recommend the test by the "Institut für Testforschung und Testentwicklung" in Leipzig:

http://www.itt-leipzig.de/static/startseiteeng.html

You can find alternatives if you search the Internet for "Wortschatztest".

Comment: I have to recommend that this answer receive the bounty. It's a solid answer, and better than anything I found while googling it.

Comment: @emaltman: it's indeed really interesting and good but I can do it only in english since to guess the "hello" obvious word I have to been able to understand the many not obvious words like: "used to express a greeting, answer a telephone, or attract attention."

Comment: @Revious, you may be right, but only for the "lower end" of the tests. The only drawback I found was that near hits or valid (although less likely) alternatives in the "productive" part of the tests can not be evaluated as such.

Comment: The other problem I found was in the "Italian - receptive" test: I scored 29/30, 29/30, 30/30, 29/30, 27/30, although Italian is my first language, and I have no problem at all with it. I scored much better in German, which is my second language, and even in English.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I repeated the "Italian - receptive" test with great care, and scored 29/30, 29/30, 30/30, 30/30, 28/30. Several questions made me scratch my head. This particular test is not reliable for sure, which of course causes the rieliability of the others to be questionable too.

Comment: @WalterTross: I'm italian too! Yes, it's a nice but very perfectible.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your vocabulary, get an Open dictionary. Free software comes with such dictionaries.

Get the number of entries in the dictionary.

```
wc -l /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.dic
72374 /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.dic
```

Now take 100 words by random from the dictionary, and count how much you know. This schould be a good estimate. For higher acccuracy take 1000 samples and divide the result by 10.

```
for dummy in {1..100}; do  z=$((RANDOM*RANDOM%72374)); sed -n ${z}p /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.dic; done
```

The result (17% = 17/100) multiplied with size of dict (17*72374/100)=12303 to get the absolute result.

Since you can concatenate substantives in German (Holzbein, Eichenholzbein, Eichenholzbeinholzvorrat) the result is open for interpretation.

Comment: @User_unknown: you know that it's a really nice idea.. maybe hard to realize (I'm a developer bit also a bit lazy) but it's nice!

Comment: I had a look at `/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic`, and found that ca. 27% of it consists of proper nouns (which you can tell from the rest because of the capital first letter). I wouldn't know how to separate proper nouns from the rest in `de_DE.dic`, unfortunately. BTW, in `.dic` files the number of entries is the content of the first line.

Comment: With `egrep -n "^a" /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic | head -n 1` you'll get the line with the first a in the first column (16709:a in my case). I'm not sure whether that is what you're after.