# How do I estimate my German vocabulary size online?

Tags: online-resource

### EN:

There are multiple "Estimate your English vocabulary size" quizzes online ([1](http://testyourvocab.com) [2](http://www.insightin.com/test/test.phtml) [3](http://my.vocabularysize.com/)). I've tried to search a German analogue, but found nothing serious enough.

Are there none or did I just search for them incorrectly?

### DE (approximate):

Es gibt viele "Messen Sie Ihre englisches Wortgut" Online-Tests ([1](http://testyourvocab.com) [2](http://www.insightin.com/test/test.phtml) [3](http://my.vocabularysize.com/)). Ich kann aber keine seriösen deutscheen Gegenstücke finden.

Gibt es keine oder suche ich schlecht?

Comment: I just found this previous question : http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11477/8784

Comment: And I think therefore that your question is a duplicate

Comment: @Elisabetta, Yes, looks duplicate. But there is no "close" button here to vote as duplicate.

Comment: @Vi.: There is. You need to have [250 reputation to get it](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) for your own questions. Otherwise you can still *flag → it is a duplicate.*